# Diameter of unitary group.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Define a function$$N: \text{End}_\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0},\text{ }N(a) := \max_{\{v \in V\,:\, |v| = 1\}} |av|.$$

What is $$\max_{a, b \in U(V)} N(a - b),$$the "diameter" of the group $U(V)$?

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that if $a\in U(V)$ then $N(a)=1$. Prove that $N(a-b)\leq N(a)+N(b)$. So if $a,b\in U(V)$ then $N(a-b)\leq 2$.

If you choose $b=-a$ and $a\in U(V)$ then $N(a-b)=N(2a)=2N(a)=2$. So the answer is 2.